# Which nanoparticles are being used or can be used to deliver drugs for the treatment of tuberculosis?

Tags: nanoscience

I am basically interested in treating tuberculosis using nanotechnology.
Anything from the field of nanotechnology be it nano particle, carbon nano tubes or any other than these (which I am not aware of) will be helpful.

Comment: https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=nanomedicine+tuberculosis&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=

Comment: Migrate to [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)  perhaps ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a physical concept.

Comment: Lungs allow a cell penetration of the largest nanoparticles of 70nm. Other tissues require 50nm while nerve cells resist up to 30nm. This is a dangerous business, because nanoparticles penetrate a cell and can easily shut down its function or cause cancer (like the particles in the tobacco smoke).

Comment: Its true that particles in tobacco smoke cause cancer but this would be happening because of their property. I mean to say that there should be some nano particles which do not show this activity and attack only the tuberculosis bacteria instead of normal lung cells.